# How to make Tchart in Delphi show ALL labels?

Tags: delphi, teechart

I've read help of `Tchart` and use different value for `LabelsSeparation`, `LabelsGridIgnoresLabelSize`, `LabelsAngle` and `LabelStyle`.

Then I have googled, but I could not find out why `Tchart` cut off name of first series, although there is plenty of free space.

```
series4.add(round(strToreal(Cells[13,1])),'Запланированный ЛС',CPW);
series5.add(round(strToreal(Cells[14,1])),'Распределенный вручную ЛС',CMW);
series6.add(round(strToreal(Cells[15,1])),'Задачи',c);
```

[image: screen]

Comment: Are you using three different series for three bars?

Comment: You can set `LabelsGridIgnoresLabelSize` on the bottom axis to  `True`, then set `LabelsSeparation` to zero. But of course, that will result in labels overlapping each other and becoming unreadable. It helps to also set `LabelsAlternate` to `True` but still it's probably better to use marks instead of labels and having linebreaks within your text.

Comment: Gunther, thank you for your suggestions! I even wrote special linebreaking function to use in labels. Funny and sad ;) It is strange that labelmultilines does not work at all.  But any way maybe you know why Tchart sometimes put labels on the top like it happened on my example? Maybe there is a way to place them on top manually? Sorry for asking but it seems that you know Tchart much better than me.

Comment: Please arrange a [simple but complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)